# java consume lot of memory ram when i use httpurlconnecion to download file ? why?

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

this is my code , when i run it , it download file correctly but use a lot of ram in may pc . ex : my RAM is 2.02 GB when i run app my RAM go up to 3GB and slow down my pc .
i use wampserver for my webserver and with my code and set http headers to may objects , i donwnload file correctly , thanks for your help.

```
private void downloadFile() {
    try {
        this.response = this.con.getInputStream();
        this.bis = new BufferedInputStream(this.response, 1024 * 1024);
        //int responseCode = this.con.getResponseCode();
        this.responseContentSize = this.con.getContentLength();

        //check kon bebin meghadare bargashti content ba on range ke to behesh gofti mosavi hast ya kheir
        if (this.responseContentSize == (this.end_range - this.start_range) + 1) {
            //fpointer = new RandomAccessFile(this.filePath, "rw");
            //fpointer.seek(this.start_range);
            byte buffer[] = new byte[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
            //out = new FileOutputStream(this.filePath);
            makeTmpFile();
            out = new FileOutputStream(this.tmpdir + this.tmpFilename);
            bos = new BufferedOutputStream(out, 1024 * 1024);
            sharedDownloadStatus.setCell(this.threadIndex, STATUS, 1);//downloading
            while (true) {
                //int read = response.read(buffer, 0, this.MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);
                int read = bis.read(buffer, 0, this.MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);
                if (read == -1)
                    break;
                //out.write(buffer, 0, read);
                //fpointer.write(buffer, 0, read);
                bos.write(buffer, 0, read);
                downloadedBytes += read;
                sharedDownloadStatus.setCell(this.threadIndex, DOWNLOADED, downloadedBytes);
            }

            if (bos != null)
                bos.close();
            if (out != null)
                out.close();
            if (fpointer != null)
                fpointer.close();
            if (bis != null)
                bis.close();
            if (response != null)
                response.close();
            sharedDownloadStatus.setCell(this.threadIndex, STATUS, 2);//finish
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        sharedDownloadStatus.setCell(this.threadIndex, STATUS, 0);//error
        log.setLog("func : downloadFile =>\n couldnt download file\n" + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: Run the app on an actual Android device and verify your statement. I assume you are seeing a jump in RAM on your PC as a result of you using an Emulator.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a megabyte buffer, but the main problem is that HttpURLConnection will buffer everything unless a fixed-length or chunked transfer mode is in effect, which is controlled by the server, not the client.

Comment: how can i say to httpurlconnection not to buffer ?